# Jsp is getting complie time error in IBM websphere 8.5

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, websphere, websphere-8

I am getting an compile time error in my jsp suddenly. Couple of days before its worked perfectly suddenly its behaving weirdly. I am getting the below error. Its happening in my production system

```
JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 414 in the file: /signOff.jsp
JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /signOff.jsp 

/apps/wbr/was/8.5/profiles/as/temp/apvra00a0037_as/ 1PPA_PnP_Cluster_apvra00a0037_as/ appOne/ testOne.war/_signOff.java : 504 : Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation

JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 414 in the file: /signOff.jsp
JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /signOff.jsp 

/apps/wbr/was/8.5/profiles/as/temp/apvra00a0037_as/ 1PPA_PnP_Cluster_apvra00a0037_as/appOne/testOne.war/_signOff.java : 504 : Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:616)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:477)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:298)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.findWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:498)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.getServletWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:338)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1010)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4047)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

This is my jsp code where its showing the error
[image]

Comment: show `signOff.jsp`

Comment: let me add the image of my code

Comment: No image, copy relevant text

Comment: Its a jsp expression we shouldn't add ; at the end

Answer (score 1):

If it just started with no code changes, I'd guess your WebSphere version was updated - maybe a fixpack applied - and something is being checked more strictly now.

I'd also try changing the JSP to put the entire scriptlet expression on one line. That is, `<%= your-variable %>`. I can't right now find any statement of whether it has to be on one line, but all the examples I've found are that way, and I've definitely seen WebSphere become more strict on things like this as fixpacks are applied.

You can also try deleting the compiled JSP file from the profile directory's `temp` directory (e.g. `/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/temp/...`) to force a fresh recompile.

Comment: sure let me try that and let u know.

Comment: Is there any patch with WAS8.5 was causing this issue?

Comment: I was asking you whether you'd recently applied a patch. You should be able to tell what version you're on. But if so, it's very possible that multi-line scriptlet expressions, and/or expressions with comments, aren't valid, and that WebSphere only now just started detecting/enforcing that.

Comment: It's my production box, we didnt have the control over it, we asked the same question websphere admin team, they are not providing any info regarding this. Thats why we researching

Answer (score 0):

After removing the commented line in between the java scriplet code, Issue is resolve. Something like this `<%versionProcess.getProcessNextVesrion(pn)%>`